# How to count values based on the other columns' conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like the following:

```
  Celebrity  Usernames
0         A          2
1         A          1
2         B          3
3         C          2
4         D          2
5         A          3
```

I want to find out how many users followed both A, C, D. So, the output should be 1. How do I do this using python?

Comment: Have you heard of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `groupby()` and `nunique()`:

```
l = ['A','C','D']
df.loc[df['Celebrity'].isin(l)].groupby('Usernames')['Celebrity'].nunique().eq(len(l))
```

Here is another way:

```
df.groupby(['Usernames','Celebrity']).size().loc[(slice(None),l)].unstack().gt(0)
```

And an alternative to crosstab:

```
df['Celebrity'].str.get_dummies().groupby(df['Usernames']).sum().loc[:,l].astype(bool).all(axis=1)
```

Using map:

```
df.loc[df['Usernames'].map(df.groupby('Usernames')['Celebrity'].agg(set).ge(set(l)))]
```

Comment: The last one returned a different value from the previous three solutions. Can you figure out why is that? Just curious. The first one already fulfilled my goal well.

Comment: Do you mean the last solution didnt return just username 2 as containing all celebrities, or the format looked different than the others?

Comment: The last solution somehow did not return the correct answer. It always returns a value that is less than what the previous three solutions return. For example, I had an adjacency matrix that shows that A and B have 27 users in common. And the first three solutions return 27. The last one gives me 17. I was not able to debug. And if I go to check the username lists, both answers have some users in common, and some users not.

Comment: I made a slight edit... changed `.eq()` to `.ge()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a crosstab, then subset to your columns and leverage the fact that `bool(0) == False` and `bool(any_other_number) == True` to see how many Usernames satisfy your condition.

```
(pd.crosstab(df['Usernames'], df['Celebrity'])
   .loc[:, ['A', 'C', 'D']]
   .astype(bool)
   .all(axis=1)
   .sum())
#1
```

---

The crosstab creates a table of counts:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Usernames'], df['Celebrity'])
#Celebrity  A  B  C  D
#Usernames            
#1          1  0  0  0
#2          1  0  1  1
#3          1  1  0  0
```

which we then susbet and turn into a Truth Table

```
pd.crosstab(df['Usernames'], df['Celebrity']).loc[:, ['A', 'C', 'D']].astype(bool)
#Celebrity     A      C      D
#Usernames                    
#1          True  False  False
#2          True   True   True
#3          True  False  False
```